# CSS :hover for empty cells :empty Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table and I want to hover every second cell or lets better say every cell with content. I want for empty cells `.table_pascals_triangle td:empty`the hover effect disabeled.

In my snippet here and on jsfiddle it works like I wanted, but on my page I see the hover effect on the empty cells, too.

```css
   .table_pascals_triangle
{empty-cells:hide;
}
.table_pascals_triangle tr.even:hover td:nth-of-type(even){
  color:black;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}
.table_pascals_triangle tr.odd:hover td:nth-of-type(odd) {
  color:black;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}
.table_pascals_triangle td:empty {
  background: white;
/* this cells shouldn't use the :hover Selector */
}
```

```html
<table class="table_pascals_triangle">
<tr class="odd">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="dreieckzahl">1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="dreieckzahl">3</td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="tetraeder">1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try `background: white!important;`

Comment: The last selector simply has a lower specificity than the ones above, so it gets ignored.

Comment: @RobinKnaapen great, it works. Could you maybe explain, why it wasn't working on my site, but here without problems, even without a `:empty` Selector in the css code it worked on jsfiddle.

Comment: It works with `!important` because `!important` increases the specifity. It isn't recommended to do so though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to append `:not(:empty)` to the selectors that do the hovering, so that you won't need a new selector afterwards that undoes the action of the first one.

The problem was one of specificity: the bottommost selector wasn't strong enough to override the above ones.

```css
   .table_pascals_triangle
{empty-cells:hide;
}
.table_pascals_triangle tr.even:hover td:nth-of-type(even):not(:empty) {
  color:black;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}
.table_pascals_triangle tr.odd:hover td:nth-of-type(odd):not(:empty) {
  color:black;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_pascals_triangle">
<tr class="odd">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="dreieckzahl">1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="dreieckzahl">3</td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="tetraeder">1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
background:white!important;
```

The hover will over rule the default background unless it's important.
You cluld also tell the hove to not look for empty cells

```
td:hover td:not(:empty)
```

I think the second option looks better but thats's up to you